# How to make card fill the entire height of a Grid Row in Ant Design?

Tags: antd

I am trying to make the height of the right Ant Design card match the height of the left Ant Design card:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-start-forked-wy6z3?file=/index.js

I can easily do it with a div, however I can't do it with a Card for some reason. Any help is appreciated since I feel like I've tried everything under the sun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing the `body` of the card and not the card container.

Instead of `bodyStyle={{ height: "100%" }}` use `style={{ height: "100%" }}`

- bodyStyle: change the body content
- style: change the entire card container
- headStyle: change the header content

Comment: Not sure why I wasn't able to make this work before! Thank you